# Adding Rich Cards data to my dotnet application cause it to crash

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to add Rich Cards to my dotnet application.

So, if I try to add this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "http://www.t-mobile.com",
  "contactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+1-877-746-0909",
    "contactType": "customer service",
    "contactOption": "TollFree",
    "areaServed": "US"
  }]
}
</script>
```

Then I get this long error message:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HL8COF5253MA": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
>   /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml(70,7): error CS0103: The name 'context' does not exist in the current context
>   /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml(71,7): error CS0103: The name 'type' does not exist in the current context
>   /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml(74,7): error CS0103: The name 'type' does not exist in the current context

Seems it tried to parse @type and @context and doesn't recognise it so it crashes. Can I prevent this some how?

Comment: Escape the `@` with `@@` to prevent razor from picking it up

Comment: trying to set your answer as the solution, but that option doesn't show up after editing the question...

Comment: Added comment as answer, you'll be able to mark it as the solution

Comment: Do not add answers in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the single occurrence of `@` that razor will pick up on with `@@` which it'll know not to process